# Ktor modify request on retry not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I have a custom retry policy on receiving 5XX errors from the server. The idea is to retry until I get a non-5XX error with an exponential delay between each retry request *also I would like to update the request body on every retry*.

Here is my code

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.java.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

suspend fun main() {
    val serverJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch { startServer() }

    val client = HttpClient(Java) {
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            connectTimeoutMillis = 5.seconds.inWholeMilliseconds
        }
        install(HttpRequestRetry)
    }

    client.post {
        url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
        setBody("Hello")
        retry {
            retryOnServerErrors(maxRetries = Int.MAX_VALUE)
            exponentialDelay(maxDelayMs = 128.seconds.inWholeMilliseconds)
            modifyRequest { it.setBody("With Different body ...") } // It's not working! if I comment this out then my retry logic works as expected
        }
    }

    client.close()
    serverJob.cancelAndJoin()
}

suspend fun startServer() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            post("/") {
                val text = call.receiveText()
                println("Retrying exponentially... $text")
                call.response.status(HttpStatusCode(500, "internal server error"))
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

As you can see, if I comment out `modifyRequest { it.setBody("With Different body ...") }` line from retry logic then everything works fine. If I include that line it only tries once and stuck there, **what I'm doing wrong here? how to change the request body for every retry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that rendering (transformation to an `OutgoingContent`) of a request body happens during the execution of the `HttpRequestPipeline`, which takes place only once after making an initial request. The HTTP request retrying happens after in the `HttpSendPipeline`.
Since you pass a String as a request body it needs to be transformed before the actual sending. To solve this problem, you can manually wrap your String into the `TextContent` instance and pass it to the `setBody` method:

```
retry {
    retryOnServerErrors(maxRetries = Int.MAX_VALUE)
    exponentialDelay(maxDelayMs = 128.seconds.inWholeMilliseconds)
    modifyRequest {
        it.setBody(TextContent("With Different body ...", ContentType.Text.Plain))
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to call suspend function inside `modifyRequest`? currently, I can do that via `runBlocking{ f() }` but I wonder if is there any coroutine way of doing it without blocking the thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.